# Fire Javascript fetch after Pressing Publish Button in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post, fetch, publish

I am fairly new to WordPress and in need of your assistance.

I need to fire a javascript fetch post request after pressing the publish button in wordpress.
This fetch will send some post related data to a URL provided to us by a 3rd party company.
I know that there are some PHP wordpress hooks like post_save that will run a function provided by you after the post has been published.

In the not wordpress world acomplishing such a task takes less then 10 min. :) but it seems wordpress has its own special way of dealing with such things ...

Your help is much appreciated!
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transition_post_status` hooks : it is triggered when a post status is changed. Then, you have to check if you new status is `publish`

```
function send_datas_on_publish($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {
        // do stuff
    }
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_datas_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```